# Firefox WebDriver (Selenium) And Security Warning Popup

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm doing some automated testing using c#, nUnit, Selenium WebDriver & Firefox.

I'm running into a problem with the Security Warning Popup:
Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

I want to disable this in Firefox, so that my testing isn't hindered.

I'm seeing conflicting reports on the internet of whether or not this is possible.
I have tried changing Firefox security warning settings using about:config but I still can't get rid of the popup (popup still shows when using WebDriver or manually using Firefox).

Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated as I've lost over 2 hours of my life on this.

A solution to stop the popup from happening or closing it automatically from WebDriver would be equally good.

Comment: I know this isn't an ideal solution, but couldn't you just identify the points when these boxes might appear and have a check for them? Then if they appear handle them by saying 'go anyway' or whichever option it allows?

Comment: I found a workaround (but it isn't really the answer to my own question). I installed a self signed certlocally http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue without any chance to bypass it: It is a builtin Firefox security feature to display this warning message, and it cannot be bypassed through a configuration flag - that's why you keep getting the message manually or via WebDriver that won't provide a bypass mechanism by clicking on the alert box.

If you want to get rid of this bugging message, consider to switch you WebDriver automated browser to Google Chrome if Firefox is not the required browser for your implementation. Chrome will not bug you with a blocking message.

Comment: Hi, I looked at using chrome, but a lot of my scripts don't work as well. As it doesn't seem to wait for the timeout I have set using:  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20)); when I use Chrome, and I now have to put in thread.sleeps, did you encounter the same problem with Chrome?

Comment: What version of the Chrome Driver are you using? We have ChromeDriver here, running around 50 tests and do not experience the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have tried un-checking all these?
[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm not seeing that dialog in Firefox that you have. I'm in the security tab on version. I'm running firefox 11, but I can't see that security warnings popup.  What version of firefox are you running that shouws those options?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I am using 3.6.28. I should have stated this originally but forgot mine was not up-to-date!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think the guys at mozilla have removed this option now to protect us from ourselves arrrrghghghghgh!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the page is being GETted via https, but is being POSTed back via http?  Or are there unsecure assets on the page that are being GETted via http?